# How do I cast a string to integer and have blank in case of error in the cast with Teradata 14.0?

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

Basically, in a SELECT statement, if a text column has a valid number in it, it should get cast to integer in result. If it is not a valid number, it should just display nothing/blank.

Right now, cast is failing when the text is not a valid number.

Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that I'm aware of.  If you search for `teradata isnumeric` you'll get a fair few UDF's that will assist you.

Comment: What version of Teradata are you running?

Answer (score 0):

With Teradata 14 you can leverage Regular Expressions to sniff out embedded character data.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR('ABC123', '[A-Za-z_]') > 0 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END;
```

Taking this step further you could try something along this line to replace alphanumeric values to NULL:

```
SELECT CAST((CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR({column}, '[A-Za-z_]') > 0 
                  THEN NULL 
                  ELSE {column} 
             END) AS SMALLINT
  FROM {MyDB}.{MyTable};
```